# inverse of a function $f(x)$, change $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the inverse of the function $f(x)= \dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-1}.$

We switch the $x$ and $y$ letters and then solve the the equation, but it became kind of complicated while solving.

Comment: Yes, you will get a quadratic equation, yielding two possible functions. BUT - you have to specify the domain, since inverses can only exist on domains where your original function is bijective.

Comment: the function is from f:(0,1)--> R

Comment: can you please help me find the functions more concretely?? @NickyHekster

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
y= \frac{2x-1}{x^2-1}.
$$
As you mentioned, switch $x$ and $y$. It becomes
$$
x= \frac{2y-1}{y^2-1}.
$$
Now, do the following steps:
$$
\begin{align}
x(y^2-1)&=2y-1\\
xy^2-x&=2y-1\\
xy^2-2y&=x-1.\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Now, multiply botth sides of $(1)$ by $x$ so that it's easy to use complete square method to obtain $y$.
$$
\begin{align}
x(xy^2-2y)&=x(x-1)\\
x^2y^2-2xy&=x^2-x\\
(xy-1)^2+1^2&=x^2-x\\
(xy-1)^2+1-1&=x^2-x-1\\
(xy-1)^2&=x^2-x-1\\
xy-1&=\pm\sqrt{x^2-x-1}\\
xy-1+1&=\pm\sqrt{x^2-x-1}+1\\
xy&=1\pm\sqrt{x^2-x-1}\\
y&=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{x^2-x-1}}{x}.\tag2
\end{align}
$$
The last step, change $y$ with $y^{-1}$ in $(2)$. Thus, the inverse is
$$
y^{-1}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{x^2-x-1}}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {2x-1}{x^2-1}=y<=>yx^2-2x+(1-y)=0$ (1). We have that $D=(-2)^2-4y(1-y)=4y^2-4y+4=4(y^2-y+1)>0$ because for $y^2-y+1$ we have $D*=(-1)^2-4=-3<0$ and the coefficient of $y^2$ is positive. Thus $D>0$ and we have two real roots of (1). You can find them and use one of them by choosing it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on the Mitsos answer
$$t(x^2-1)=2x-1\\tx^2-2x-t+1=0\\x_{1,2}=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-4t(1-t)}}{2t}$$